# Hide() dropdown contents makes it disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm new to Javascript so this may be a stupid question, but I'm at a loss. I've been trying to get my dropdown to hide/close when the right list item is selected. I'm using the hover dropdown provided by [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp). I've copied the CSS they've provided and my HTML and JS look like this:

```
<div class="dropdown" id = "menu3">
    <button class="dropbtn" id = "menu3btn">Menu 3</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id = "menu3c">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="item30">Cheese</a></li>
            <li><a id="item31">Pepperoni</a></li>
            <li><a id="item32">Sausage</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
        if($(this).text() == "Sausage"){
            $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        }
    }
}
```

The current Javascript is closing the dropdown if the user clicks "Sausage", which is what I want. But when I hover over the menu again, the dropdown doesn't open/show. I've tried changing

```
$(this).parent().parent().hide();
```

to
    $(this).parent().hide();

and the results are the same.

I've also tried to toggle the dropbtn by replacing the parent().hide() code with:

```
var btnName = "#"+$(this).parent().parent().parent().attr("id")+"btn";
$(btnName).toggle();
```

This removed the button and dropdown menu from the screen entirely.

I've also tried forcing the hover to show hidden dropdown-content by adding this method to my JS:

```
$(".dropdown").hover(function() {
    if($(this).attr("id") == "menu3"){
        $("#menu3c").show();
    }
}
```

This didn't do anything either (the hidden content stayed hidden).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you are wanting to use JavaScript for this instead of using pure CSS?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with CSS so JavaScript was easier for me to write. I'd be open to any suggestions in CSS though.

Comment: can you create a demo that shows your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(this).parent().parent().hide();`, you can use this to hide the parent

`$(this).closest('div').hide();`

To show the menu again,

```
$('#menu3btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#menu3c').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and the menu shows up again after I click (thank you). Is there any way to make it show up from hovering over the button?

Comment: you just need replace hover $('#menu3btn').on('hover', function() {
    $('#menu3c').toggle();
});